# monodroid - writing data into text

Tags: text, ip, xamarin.android

I have an IP part including an IP address that can be changed in the future.

I want to be able to read this IP address and write it into a text file that I created in Assets file.

I couldn't handle this problem. Saving might be into another path. I just want to read that address and every-time I open application, I want to see the last IP address I entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is NOT possible to override files in Assets. Assets are meant to be static files that never change. However what you want to accomplish is not impossible.

I can think of a couple of ways to achieve this.

**1. Using `SharedPreferences`**

Have a default value somewhere in your code. When you enter a new IP address you want to connect to, or whatever you do with it, save it to `SharedPreferences` and check on startup if the `key/value` pair in the `SharedPreferences` has been set and load that instead of the default.

**2. Using either app personal storage or SD Card**

Just like `SharedPreferences` however on first startup of the application create a file either in the Personal storage or on the SD card with the default value, then override it when you enter a new value in the application.